# Why declare "private List contactInfos" without a generic ("private List <ContactInfo> contactInfos")?

Tags: java, generics, google-app-engine

In this example from the [App Engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Dependent_Children_and_Cascading_Deletes), why does the example declare `contactInfos` like this (no Generics):

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Element;
// ...
    @Persistent
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private List contactInfos;
```

instead of like this, using a Generic:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Element;
// ...
    @Persistent
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private List <ContactInfo> contactInfos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics aren't required, just highly recommended.

Specifying `List<ContactInfo>` is absolutely doable in App Engine, I can't imagine it was an indication that generic lists aren't allowed in App Engine.